# Where are the MatrixXd and VectorXd define in Eigen(c++)? I can't find the definition of them through the grep command

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I search through the entire source code of Eigen(https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror), but can not fine the definition of some types such as MatrixXd and VectorXd.

The document of Eigen(https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__matrixtypedefs.html#ga99b41a69f0bf64eadb63a97f357ab412) says that MatrixXd is defined as

```
typedef Matrix< double , Dynamic , Dynamic > Eigen::MatrixXd
```

but I didn't find them is the source code.

Comment: Seems hard to make self-contained...? | Which `grep` command did you use?

Comment: grep -r MatrixXd ./

Comment: Instead of writing thanks comment you can just upvote and accept the answer. (read the [help] to know what are those)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MatrixXd` is defined by the expansion of the macro `EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS_ALL_SIZES(double, d)` on line [451 of Matrix.h](https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror/blob/c91be04982782b09330d67d0abaae273d546679a/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h#L451).

In fact, that macro ends up expanding to the typedefs for `Matrix2d`, `Vector2d`, `RowVector2d`, `Matrix3d`, `Vector3d`, `RowVector3d`, `Matrix4d`, `Vector4d`, `RowVector4d`, `MatrixXd`, `VectorXd`, `RowVectorXd`, `Matrix2Xd`, `MatrixX2d`, `Matrix3Xd`, `MatrixX3d`, `Matrix4Xd`, and `MatrixX4d`.